# dplyr::select(-.data$row_id) syntax causing issues on server but not local computer

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the same version of dplyr (1.0.10) on my local computer and on our CentOS 7 cluster, however the following function is giving an error on the cluster but not on my local computer.

```
function (x) 
{
    data.frame(x) %>% tibble::rowid_to_column("row_id") %>% dplyr::mutate(dummy = 1) %>% 
        tidyr::spread(x, .data$dummy, fill = 0) %>% dplyr::select(-.data$row_id) %>% 
        as.matrix
}
```

Error:

> simpleError in dplyr::select(., -.data$row_id): :1:5: unexpected symbol
> 1: Use of
>                ^

The function is called as part of `RunHarmony` from `immunogenomics/harmony`.

I can't think why this would be so any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems to be related to `source`: for example `source(textConnection("a<-1; b c"))` throws `textConnection("a<-1; b c"):1:9: unexpected symbol
1: a<-1; b c"` which means that the interpreter found the words "Use of" somewhere in the source code...

Comment: Thank you. The error goes away if you change `dplyr::select(-.data$row_id)` to `dplyr::select(-row_id)` but I'm not sure why it would work in the original form locally but not on CentOS 7.